# Excel VBA Create range validation input message from range comment

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with making what seems to me a simple Excel VBA routine, we have a spreadsheet where comments were used instead of validation input messages. I would like to loop the spreadsheet and replace all these comments by validation messages.

Update: Some cells already have a validation containing a dropdown list. This dropdown list must be preserved.

I made a attempt but I am failing to create the input message from the comment.text. Can someone please explain why this is going wrong and what I should change?

Thank you

```
Sub EditComments()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("A19:AA655")


    For Each cell In rng
        Dim oCell As Range
        Set oCell = cell
        oCell.Select
        With oCell


            If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                Dim oComment As Comment
                Set oComment = .Comment

                Dim oValidation As Validation
                Set oValidation = .Validation

                With oCell.Validation
                    .InputMessage = oComment.Text
                End With

                oComment.Delete
            End If

        End With


    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try

```
Sub EditComments()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rng As Range, oCell As Range
    Set rng = Range("A19:AA655")
    For Each oCell In rng
        With oCell
            'check if cell contain comment.
            If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then

              'check if cell not contain dropdown then do something
              If .Validation Is Nothing Then
                 With .Validation
                 .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
                    .InputTitle = "Message"
                    .InputMessage = oCell.Comment.Text
                 End With
              Else 'if contain dropdown
                With .Validation
                    .InputTitle = "Message"
                    .InputMessage = oCell.Comment.Text
                End With
              End If
              .Comment.Delete

              End If

            End If
        End With
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please Read: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.inputmessage)

Comment: Thank you for this code, I updated my question, some cells might have dropdown menu and I would like to keep this. Now the code errors on these cells with dropdown box.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, and the code does nothing. The previous code was OK, but if there is a dropdownbox the comment also should be used as inputmessage with the dropdownbox still functional.